# execve shellcode writing segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, shellcode, execve

I am trying to study execve shellcode,

OS : Linux bt 2.6.39.4

root@bt:~/exploit# cat gshell.s

```
.globl _start

_start:

    nop
    jmp MyString

    shell:

            popl %esi
            xorl %eax,%eax

            movl %al,9(%esi)
            movl %esi,10(%esi)
            movl %eax,14(%esi)

            movb $11,%al
            movl %esi, %ebx
            leal 0xa(%esi),%ecx
            leal 0xe(%esi),%edx
            int $0x80



            movl $1,%eax
            movl $0,%ebx
            int $0x80


    MyString:
            call shell
            shellvar:
                    .ascii "/bin/bashADDDDCCCC"
```

root@bt:~/exploit# as -gstabs -o gshell.o gshell.s

root@bt:~/exploit# ld -o gshell gshell.o

root@bt:~/exploit# ./gshell
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
root@bt:~/exploit#

### GDB:

(gdb) break *_start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048054: file gshell.s, line 6.

(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/exploit/gshell

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
shell () at gshell.s:14
14                      movb %al,9(%esi)

(gdb) print /x $esi
$1 = 0x804807a
(gdb) x/16cb $esi
0x804807a :   47 '/'  98 'b'  105 'i' 110 'n' 47 '/'  98 'b'  97 'a'  115 's'
0x8048082 : 104 'h' 65 'A'  68 'D'  68 'D'  68 'D'  68 'D'  67 'C'  67 'C'
(gdb)

from above output it seems I have successfully pope'd /bin/sh address into ESI register
But when I try to move 0 into 9(%esi) --> It causes segmentation fault.
Even tried to modify this program  :  movl $0 to $esi.
Want to know if it is restricted to write at 0x804807a address? which causing this fault?
and how i can proceed with successfully running this shellcode

Thanks,
littlejack

Comment: Isn't the string part of the code segment, which is write protected?

Comment: But then any other way i can make this shell code successful?

Answer (score 4):

As Bo said in his comment, the `.text` section is read-only by default on current systems. To make this code work, you have to make it writable. You can for example use a directive in the source file like so:

```
.section wtext, "awx", @progbits
```

The equivalent `nasm` directive is:

```
section wtext exec write
```

Alternatively, could also pass the `-N` switch to the linker.

Note that such shell code is normally intended for stack execution, which is yet another thing that's typically disabled in current operating systems. If you ever want to try this on the stack, you might need the `-z execstack` linker option.

Comment: Thanks Jester, Bo ..appreciate your help, I tried both methods and worked for me .. .section wtext, "awx", @progbits method seems perfect!!! as we don't need to pass -N switch