# Segmentation fault while executing shell in assembly code

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, buffer-overflow

I'm a newbie to assembly programming. I'm getting a segmentation fault in the following program. Any help would be appreciated. 
The program essentially executes a bash shell using the execv system call (system call no 11).

```
.text
.globl _start

 _start:
    jmp callshell

    shellcode:
            popl %esi
            xorl %eax, %eax
            movb $0,%al
            movb %al,0x9(%esi)
            movl %esi,0xa(%esi)
            movl %eax,0xe(%esi)
            movb $11, %al
            movl %esi, %ebx
            leal 0xa(%esi),%ecx
            leal 0xe(%esi),%edx
            int $0x80

    callshell:
            call shellcode
            shellvariables:
                    .ascii "/bin/bashABBBBCCCC"
```

Comment: what's the description of the segmentation fault ??

Comment: Your `shellvariables` stuff is all in `.text` section which is read-only by default. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777445/execve-shellcode-writing-segmentation-fault).

Comment: I used the '-N' flag as you mentioned @Jester. There's no segmentation fault as before. However, the bash shell is not being spawned. Also, I'm executing this on a machine where the stack protection mechanisms like Stack randomization (ASLR) are turned off.

Answer (score 0):

What's the meaning of these combined hexadecimal prefixes?

```
int $0x80
```

Could it be DS is not pointing to your .TEXT section?