# Shellcode segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I started to learn about shellcode on linux. I am getting a segmentation fault when linking below assembly code. May you help why I get this fault. Thanks in advance.

```
root@KaliLinux:~/Desktop# cat Untitled\ Document
1       .text
2
3       .globl _start
4
5       _start:
6
7                               jmp GetString
8
9                       ShellCode:
10                                      popl %esi
```

Pops the address of the string.

```
11                                      xorl %eax,%eax
12                                      movb %al, 0x9(%esi)
```

writes NULL to 10th element of the string. But I got segmentation fault here.

```
13                                      movl %esi, 0xa(%esi)
14                                      movl %eax, 0xe(%esi)
15                                      movb $11, %al
16                                      movl %esi, %ebx
17                                      leal 0xa(%esi), %ecx
18                                      leal 0xe(%esi), %edx
19                                      int $0x80
20
21
22                      GetString:
23                              call ShellCode
24                              String:
25                                      .ascii "/bin/bashABBBBCCCC"
```

GDB output

```
(gdb) break 11
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048057: file exeshellused.a, line 11.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/OSEZEN/exeshellused
Breakpoint 1, ShellCode () at exeshellused.a:11
11                                      xorl %eax,%eax
(gdb) x/1s $esi
0x8048073 <String>:      "/bin/bashABBBBCCCC"
```

confirms that I got the address of the string.

```
(gdb) s
12                                      movb %al, 0x9(%esi)
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x0      0
ecx            0x0      0
edx            0x0      0
ebx            0x0      0
esp            0xbffff590       0xbffff590
ebp            0x0      0x0
esi            0x8048073        134512755
edi            0x0      0
eip            0x8048059        0x8048059 <ShellCode+3>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x73     115
ss             0x7b     123
ds             0x7b     123
es             0x7b     123
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
(gdb) s
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
ShellCode () at exeshellused.a:12
12                                      movb %al, 0x9(%esi)
```

Comment: Duplicate of [execve-shellcode-writing-segmentation-fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777445/execve-shellcode-writing-segmentation-fault)

Comment: @Jester: Yes, even seems to be EXACTLY the duplicate question!