# Null terminating using movb causes segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, buffer-overflow

This is my linux64 assembly code (working fine):

```
.text
.globl  _start
.type   _start, @function
_start:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp
        jmp helper
shellcode:
        pop     %rdx
        movq    %rdx, -16(%rbp)
        xorq    %rax,%rax
        movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
        leaq    -16(%rbp), %rcx
        xorl    %edx, %edx
        movq    %rcx, %rsi
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        xorl    %eax,%eax
        movb    $59,%al
        syscall
        leave
        ret
helper:
        call shellcode
        .ascii "/bin/sh\0"
```

now I want to null terminate the string by changing `.ascii "/bin/sh\0"` to something like `.ascii "/bin/shM"` and replace the `M` with `Null` inside the code. But it doesn't work and I get segmentation fault:

```
    .text
    .globl  _start
    .type   _start, @function
    _start:
            pushq   %rbp
            movq    %rsp, %rbp
            subq    $16, %rsp
            jmp helper
    shellcode:
            pop     %rdx
            movq    %rdx, -16(%rbp)
            xorq    %rax,%rax
########### Next line causes segmentation fault 
            movb    %al, 7(%rdx)
            movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
            leaq    -16(%rbp), %rcx
            xorl    %edx, %edx
            movq    %rcx, %rsi
            movq    %rax, %rdi
            xorl    %eax,%eax
            movb    $59,%al
            syscall
            leave
            ret
    helper:
            call shellcode
            .ascii "/bin/shM"
```

I used `gdb` to debug and everything seems fine:

- address of `"/bin/shM"` is correctly popped in `rdx`
- `7(%rdx)` is correctly address of the last character which is `M`
- Byte value of the last character is correctly `0x4d` which is character `M`

Why can't I move a null byte `%al` to `7(%rdx)` and how can I fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't spam tags.

Comment: @olaf that's why you downvoted? it was suggested by the website , should've taken a screenshot

Comment: There are no suggestions. Just matching names. And you should not assume someone downvoted just befcause he leaves a comment. It could be understood as offence.

Comment: That string is in .text so probably read-only. If you want it to be writable, put it in .data. And/or just terminate it with a zero to begin with, because why are you even doing it at runtime?

Comment: @harold thank you ! i'll try it ! it's part of our assignment to do it at runtime

Comment: @harold thanks it worked!! please write it as an answer so that I can select it as the answer

Comment: I don't understand the downvote really. I wish the person would've explained the issue with my question so that I can improve it

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777445/execve-shellcode-writing-segmentation-fault/13777931).