# How do I manage a struct from a JMP CALL POP routine?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am writing a bind shell in assembly and as part of the code, I need to write to a struct. Since my end goal is to create shellcode, I want to avoid null bytes (0x00). For this, I have tried to do the JMP CALL POP routine which handles labels through grabbing the parameter from `call`

I have simplified my code to remove all of the bind shell components and only use the part to modify the struct section. The code, however, segfaults when I mov data into that memory at the address stored in the register (pointing at the struct)

I am running on 64 bit RHEL and using nasm. This whole routine worked when I just used labels, but this lead to null bytes, so I'm trying the JMP CALL POP technique.

```
section .text
   global _start
_start:
   jmp call_val
   nop
call_val:
   call val
   data times 16 db 0
val:
   pop r9
   xor rax, rax
   add rax, 8
   mov [r9], rax
```

I have confirmed that r9 is populated with the address of my struct, in the data label. The rax register is also loaded with an 8. I expect for the code to place an 8 in the first 8 bytes of the total 16 bytes in the mov statement. Instead, it segfaults on the mov statement.

Comment: `.text` is read only by default. Won't be an issue with stack, but that in exchange won't be executable :) See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13777931/547981)

Comment: Thank you! I've been setting stack as executable anyway so I think I'll go with that.

Comment: A forward `call` will have zero bytes in the `rel32` displacement so it's useless for shellcode.  This is why the data has to go at the end: you `jmp` forward to a `call` that jumps *backward* to a `pop`.  Or in x86-64 you can use RIP-relative addressing after a forward `jmp` over your non-zero data.  See also [Avoiding 0xFF bytes in shellcode using CALL to read RIP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/55778839)

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you so much! I was confused as to why I was still getting the zero bytes. Also, I rewrote this code with just modifying the stack, and I'll probably make a version that utilizes JMP CALL POP for the sake of this post. Is it best practice to for me to post an answer with what I've done?