# sigsegv on xchg byte [esi+1], al modifying code in the .text section

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm, shellcode

I'm currently working on a shellcode for Linux x86. Currently on my system ASLR and DEP are disabled.
I've implemented a small assembly "decoder" which will swap couple of bytes in my shellcode (is a sample execve) (re-ordering all of it), before directly jumping into it.

Both the shellcode and the assembly decoder are working fine when I assemble them into an object, extract the byte sequence (I already checked, no null bytes :)) and call them from a C function wrapper.

Main problem is that if I assemble the NASM decoder in ELF and try to debug it inside GDB, the decoder will crash with a **sigsegv** error on line: `xchg byte [esi+1], al`

Why does it happen in the first place? Why it is not working in GDB when linked and executed directly from ASM but it's perfectly fine when launched from the C wrapper?

Here my decoder in NASM:

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
    jmp short shellcode_section     ; goto shellcode_section

decoder:                    ; decoder's main
    pop esi                 ; load address of our encoded shellcode (encoded_shellcode) into ESI (JMP CALL POP trick)
    mul ecx                 ; trick to clear eax and exc
    mov cl, 10              ; loop half the times of our shellcode length as we are swapping two bytes at time (eg. shellcode length is 20)

decode_loop:
    mov  al, byte [esi]         ; load encoded_shellcode's byte pointed by ESI in al    | [A][B] al=A
    xchg byte [esi+1], al           ; swap al value with next byte value (ESI+1)        | [A][A] al=B
    mov [esi], al               ; load swapped byte in al to location pointed by ESI    | [B][A]
        add esi, 2              ; select next byte "couple"             
        loop decode_loop            ; cl is 0? No, we go back at decode_loop and execute the cicle again
        jmp short encoded_shellcode     ; cl is 0, we've decoded all our shellcode and we can now directly jump into it

shellcode_section:
        call decoder                ; goto decoder's main, putting encoded_shellcode on the stack
        encoded_shellcode: db 0xc0, 0x31, 0x68, 0x50, 0x2f, 0x2f, 0x68, 0x73, 0x2f, 0x68, 0x69, 0x62, 0x87, 0x6e, 0xb0, 0xe3, 0xcd, 0x0b, 0x90, 0x80
```

- I usually assemble the NASM code with: `nasm -f elf32 file.nasm`
- link the object with: `ld -m elf_i386 -o out file.o`
- extract the byte sequence with: `objdump -d file.o`

And I'm currently using the following C wrapper:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

unsigned char code[] = "SHELLCODE";

main()
{

    printf("Shellcode Length:  %d\n", strlen(code));

    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;

    ret();

}
```

compiling it with `gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack file.c -o shellcode`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because you used `-z execstack` for the C version but in the standalone version your `.text` section is read-only.

Comment: @Jester: IIRC, `-z execstack` only makes all sections *executable*.  You need to link with `-N` aka `--omagic` to make `.text` writeable  (So `gcc -Wl,-N`).  You could put `section .data` before the misleading-named `shellcode_section` label (which is just a label and doesn't change sections), then `gcc -z execstack` would work.

Comment: Yeah what I should have said was the C version has the code in the `.data` section which is writable, but the standalone has it in `.text` which is not.

Comment: @ppound: Also, `mov [esi], al` is a store, not a load.  The comment uses the wrong terminology.  Also, a much easier and more efficient way to swap is `rol word [esi], 8` to swap bytes.  Or if you did want to load/store, do a word load and store AH and AL.  Or vice versa with a word store after 2 byte loads: fewer stores but more partial-register performance penalties.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13777931/547981)

Comment: Thank you guys, I would have missed that completely. Was a "stupid" mistake but I was unable to find it.